share conda environments between devices using a cloud
How can I share conda environments between two (or more computers) automatically, so that changes I make on one device are available on the other the next time too? (think of PC and Laptop with the same OS)
So far I think there are two options for this, but I cannot find the relevant information to decide which could work:

have a shell script that creates a new .yml every time a change on the environment is made and that loads the .yml from the cloud on starup and checks for updates. This should be save as the devices still have their own local environment but might be hard to automatise compleatly
directly tell conda to install environments in the cloud. Is it that simple or does this mess up my environments?


I just figured this out myself. I have successfully accessed the same environment from two computers on Windows using the cloud without using .yml
On First Computer:

Create environment with name "my_env" on google drive desktop folder such as "G:\My Drive\conda_envs\my_env" (I do not know if other cloud services work. I only know that the desktop version of google drive does work)

On Second computer:

install anaconda, google drive desktop.

locate the default conda environment directory name:   "C:\Users\YourUsername\Anaconda3\envs"

Use command prompt to create a symbolic link:
mklink /D "C:\Users\YourUsername\Anaconda3\envs\my_env" "G:\My Drive\conda_envs\my_env"


please note that "my_env" is included at the end of the first set of quotations.

Use anaconda prompt and type:
Conda info --envs
or use Anaconda Navigator to look at the linked environment

On VS Code using 'Python: Select Interpreter' also shows the connected environment and works properly


Google Drive Desktop should sync the files automatically. On your two computers, remember to set your google drive environment folder to be available offline.
